# What do %svelte.head% and %svelte.body% represent?

Tags: sveltekit

Absolute noob to Svelte workflows, but it's been strongly recommended by people I respect and I want to get to grips with it.

Kind of pretty clear so far, but when I worked through the SvelteKit setup and docs, I wasn't able to understand exactly what those two tags mean in the `app.html`

Comment: This question is critical for someone wading through another person's Svelte code and trying to figure out what means what.

Answer (score 15):

These symbols are templates for the project. `%svelte.head%` is replaced with the contents of the special `svelte:head` tag and `%svelte.body%` is replaced by anything you have in your svelte file for that route and the contents of the `svelte:body` tag. Whenever your project is compiled, it will replace the template tags with their corresponding special tag.